# Why is onCreate() method not being called?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oncreate

I made a new class and I wanted to make an OnClickListener for a button but I notice that the onCreate wasn't being called. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class BedtimeBottomSheet extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "BedtimeBottomSheet";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: so you should paste in your OnClickListener code.

Comment: please read : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities

Comment: Are you displaying this activity? If so, how? It has no view set... If this is just some class, and not actually an activity it should *not* extend the activity class.

Comment: @TylerV This class is use for a bottom sheet,  if I remove the activity then how do I make it run on start/create?

Comment: Those are part of the activity lifecycle, if this is not an activity it should not and will not run those at all. Maybe you should show more in the question about how you create and use this class and what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I'm trying to make a setOnClickListener on a button  This is the code that im running https://privatebin.net/?85429f280fb147b0#8qN5ETWfUxHCAJLEvzhWv9NF8SiB8XPaiYWXwrim2rxn

Comment: Then you can just use `button.setOnClickListener`, why do you need another class? **Please** do not add code as a comment, it is unreadable. Edit the question. Where is the code you posted located? In this fake activity class? If so, also show how that is used.

Comment: The code you pasted is not in a valid activity. You **cannot** simply make a random class that extends Activity and expect it to work/run onCreate etc. Show us where this is used in the *actual* activity class you have. The TextView in the code you pasted will always be null - that "activity" has no view set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you should use `setContentView(binding.getRoot());` in your `onCreate` method.